# combobox jquery onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, thymeleaf

How i update combobox based on another combobox, i have this code but its not work, can someone help me. Thanks

```
  <select name="marca" id="marca" onchange="javascript:carregaModelos(this.value)" >
    <option th:each="marca : ${marcas}" 
      th:value="${marca.idmarca}" 
      th:text="${marca.nomemarca}">Marca</option>
</select>

     <select   name="modelo" id="modelo">
  <option th:each="modelo : ${modelos}" 
      th:value="${idmodelo}" 
      th:text="${nomemodelo}">Modelo</option>
     </select>


<script type="text/javascript">     
   function carregaModelos(marca) { 
 var opcao = $(this).('#marca option')   
 console.log(opcao);
 jQuery("#modelo").load( "pesquisa/" + opcao);
 return false;


}
```

and this

```
 @RequestMapping("/pesquisa/{idmarca}")
    public String pesquisa(ModelMap model, @PathVariable Long idmarca) {
        model.addAttribute("modelo", service.obterModelosByMarcas(idmarca));
        return "index";
```

Comment: Provide HTML output that helps understand your final content of both comboboxes.

Comment: i need just to print the result of choosing the combobox, i dont have more code.for example: when i choose from first combobox, this  will update option of second ,  and after choose the second 
print the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an attribute with value to target element.

`data-target-sync="#targetElementId"`

> The value is jQuery selector so `#` included with ID of target element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('[data-target-sync]').change(function() {

    var cur = $(this);

    $(cur.attr('data-target-sync')).val(cur.val());

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="marca" id="marca" data-target-sync="#modelo">
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
  <option value="c">C</option>


</select>

<select name="modelo" data-target-sync="#marca" id="modelo">
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
  <option value="c">C</option>

</select>
```